# Never heard back after recruiting company asked for phone interview

Tags: interviewing, recruitment

A recruiter contacted me by email regarding a job I applied for to set up a phone call. I gave her my availability but never heard back.

I'm just curious as to what could be the reason. Forgot? Had a second look at my resume and didn't like it?

Note: She contacted me 3 days ago and my availability was today morning. I never received email confirmation either.

Comment: How long have it been?

Comment: She contacted me 3 days ago and my availability was today morning. I never received email confirmation either.

Comment: @WantsToLearn I added your comment to the question body, as it is very useful info.

Comment: It's really not possible for us to speculate, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have it wrong. Regardless of the positivity you received when contacting the recruiter, he or she may have 100 applications to deal with at the moment, or a workload of their own, such as staff meetings, etc.

It's totally up to you to show you're the best person they can hire for the job. There are no expectations you can have on the recruiter, his or her expectations are from his or her management to fill the vacant or newly opened position.

It really is up to you to show interest - give the recruiter a day or two at the most, then follow-up and just remind him or her of who you are and your conversation the other day. Recruiters are human.

Good luck in finding a new position for you to grow, and befriend new colleagues! :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe. Maybe not. We don't know, we can't tell.

- Maybe your and your interviewer's availability did not overlap.
- Maybe the requirement is already filled up from some other source.
- Maybe your interview appointment/invite process fell through the gap.

We can only guess. We cannot provide a definite answer.

Word of advice: If this is a recent (2-3 days) incident, you can get in touch with the recruiter and ask abut any updates/ plans. If it's more than that (more than a week already), and you had your (one or multiple) availability within this time - it's hard luck. Try elsewhere.